# When can one use the Leibniz rule for integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

If I want to determine determine the following expression
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \int_{a}^{b} f(x, t)\mathrm{d}x 
\end{align*}
is it sufficient that $f_n\left(x, t+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is uniformly converging to $f(x, t)$ in order to be allowed to apply the Leibniz rule, i.e.
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \int_{a}^{b} f(x, t)\mathrm{d}x =
\int_{a}^{b}  \frac{\partial }{\partial t} f(x, t)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
given that $a, b$ are independent of $t$? If not, which conditions are sufficient for being able to use Leibniz' rule (I have not learned about the dominated convergence theorem yet)?

Comment: What do you mean by “$f_n(x, t + 1 / n)$ converging uniformly to $f(x, c)$”? Do you mean $f(x, t + 1 / n)$ converging uniformly to $f(x, t)$?

Comment: @Frank oh yes, there is a little typo which I corrected now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR,** if the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is jointly continuous in the variables $x$ and $t$, then the Leibniz rule works. If you use the Lebesgue integral (which gives you the dominated convergence theorem), this condition can be relaxed.

#### Leibniz rule for Riemann integration

When working with Riemann integrals, the standard criterion for switching a limit and an integral sign is the following statement (this is, in fact, a special case of the dominated convergence theorem), which relies on uniform convergence:

> **Theorem 1.** (Interchanging limits and integrals) If $g_n : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of Riemann integrable functions that converges uniformly to a Riemann integrable function $g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b g_n(x)\mathrm{d}x 
> = \int_a^b g(x)\mathrm{d}x.
> $$

Using this result, we can establish a Leibniz rule for Riemann integration. Because notation with multiple variables can get confusing, let us define $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$$
F(t) = \int_a^b f(x, t)\mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $f : [a, b] \times \mathbb{R}$ is the function in your question. For a fixed $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we would like to find if $F'(t_0)$ exists and whether it can be obtained by the Leibniz rule. The key observation is that we can write differentiation as the limit
$$
\tag{1}
F'(t_0)
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(t_0 + h) - F(t_0)}{h}
= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_a^b \frac{f(x, t_0 + h) - f(x, t_0)}{h} \mathrm{d}x.
$$
To apply Theorem 1, we would like the *difference quotient* to converge uniformly. (That is to say, for every sequence $h_n \to 0$, the difference quotient $\frac{f(x, t_0 + h_n) - f(x, t_0)}{h_n}$ should converge uniformly in $x$.) However, the difference quotient is a bit unwieldy to work with, but we can use the mean-value theorem to instead write
$$
\tag{2}
F'(t_0)
= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t_0 + h_x) \mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $|h_x| \leq |h|$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. This leads to the following result.

> **Theorem 2.** (Leibniz rule for Riemann integration) Let $f, F, t_0$ be defined as above. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is continuous on a rectangle $[a, b] \times [t_0 - \delta, t_0 + \delta]$, then $F'(t_0)$ exists and is given by the formula
> $$
> F'(t_0) = \int_a^b \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial t}(x, t_0) \mathrm{d}x.
> $$
> In particular, if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is continuous on all of $[a, b] \times \mathbb{R}$, $F$ is differentiable everywhere and can be determined by the Leibniz rule.

By $(2)$, it suffices to show that for all sequences $h_n \to 0$, the functions $$g_n(x) := \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t_0 + (h_n)_x)$$ converge uniformly to $g(x) := \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x)$. This can be done by utilizing the uniform continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$. I'll leave the rest of the proof to you.

Also, (if I'm understanding correctly) your criterion of $f(x, t + 1 / n)$ converging uniformly to $f(x, t)$ doesn't exactly work. For one, it says nothing about the uniform convergence of the difference quotient in $(1)$ since it only works with discrete time steps of $1 / n$. Even if $f(x, t + h)$ were to converge uniformly to $f(x, t)$ as $h \to 0$, it would not guarantee uniform convergence of the difference quotient (it does not even guarantee the existence of a derivative!).

#### Leibniz rule for Lebesgue integration

Finally, here's a criterion for the Leibniz rule if we are using the Lebesgue integral.

> **Theorem 3.** (Leibniz rule for Lebesgue integration) Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f : [a, b] \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue integrable function such that the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t)$ exists everywhere. Further suppose there is a Lebesgue integrable function $g : [a, b] \to [0, +\infty]$ such that $\int_a^b g(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is finite and
> $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t)\right| \leq g(x)$
> for all $t \in X$ and $x \in [a, b]$. Then
> $$
> \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_a^b f(x, t)\mathrm{d}x
> = \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t) \mathrm{d}x.
> $$

Observe that Theorem 3 supersedes Theorem 2 because continuous functions are bounded on compact subsets. Setting $X = [t_0 - \delta, t_0 + \delta]$ and setting $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ to be a constant bound of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ on $X$, Theorem 2 follows.

The proof of Theorem 3 is arguably easier than in the case of Riemann integration, at least if one is equipped with the machinery of measure theory. After obtaining $(2)$, the result follows directly from the dominated convergence theorem.